# How to populate list View with files that are saved in SQL database using Win Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can upload and save files from list View into SQL database, but I can not fetch the files saved in the database to display in list view. I also want the files that are fetched from the database to display their associated icons in list view control. The attached picture shows how it was uploaded from folder browser dialog to list view. I have searched the internet and read about bitmap, byte conversion yet i don't know how to apply it on list view control. Below is my codes, kindly assist me

```
    private void btnfolderbrowserdlg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        listFiles.Clear();
        listView.Items.Clear();           
        using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog() { Description = "Select your path." })
        {
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
                {                        
                    imageList.Images.Add(System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(item));
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(item);
                    listFiles.Add(fi.FullName);                                                  
                    listView.Items.Add(fi.Name, imageList.Images.Count - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
    
    private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        foreach (ListViewItem i in listView.Items)
        {
            string qry = @"INSERT INTO taskSCL2 ( FileName)VALUES(convert(varbinary(MAX), @d2))";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d24", images)).Value = i.SubItems[0].ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    }

    private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-6G40H6Q\KANASERVER;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FileName FROM tbldocument", con))
            {                   
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                                    
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {                        
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["FileName"].ToString());                       
                    listView.Items.Add(item);
                }
                listView.View = View.List;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `con` is never declared for `btnSave_Click()` You should not try to re-use the same SqlConnection throughout your app; it really is better to create a new instance for most queries. Also, `AddWithValue()` can be dangerous for performance.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, l have never encountered trouble using the way l insert data into database, but l'll consider your advice. The codes are working fine except loading list view with file file from database

Answer (score 0):

I think first. You need to have a List View Template. Then with binding you will be able to show what you need. [An example](https://wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/)